# Semanage command not found in Fedora 27 droplet from Digital Ocean

Tags: fedora, selinux, dnf

Just getting started with Selinux on a Fedora 27 droplet from Digital Ocean. Apparently the `semanage` command is not installed by default. Every tutorial I've read refers to this command. I need to set the selinux context for a directory that contains a systemd-nspawn container. Normally we would run something like this:

```
$ semanage fcontext -a -t svirt_sandbox_file_t "/path/to/mycontainer(/.*)?"
$ restorecon -R /path/to/mycontainer/
```

Very surprised to find Fedora 27's documentation is not up-to-date on selinux. Just a hodge-podge of old docs and articles that refer primarily to `yum` packages, stating that the selinux tools are installed by default. All of them refer to the `semanage` command.

I mean, if I `sudo dnf search selinux`, a million packages show up, including the `policycoreutils` packages, which seem to be the ones that most of the tutorials refer to. But I'm more concerned with the lack of information. I thought selinux shipped complete on Fedora.

What am I missing here? Is there another way of setting selinux context? Should `semanage` work out of the box on Fedora?

Comment: `$ rpm -qf --qf '%{name}\n' $(which semanage)`
`policycoreutils-python-utils`

Comment: You may want to use `sestatus` to see if SELinux is actually available though.

Comment: Sestatus shows selinux is enabled. The above command outputs error: no such file or directory.

Comment: I can easily dnf install the policycoreutils packages but as mentioned, I thought selinux was ready to go on Fedora so I assumed that I was missing something. Take care.

Comment: Yes, you're missing the package I indicated...

Comment: But why isn't policycoreutils installed by default?

Comment: @JayElston that’s what I was wondering :)

Answer (score 2):

On my installation vm (Not on DO) I simply did the following:

```
1 - [sudo] yum provides semanage
policycoreutils-python-utils-2.7-4.fc27.x86_64 : SELinux policy core python utilities
Repo        : @System
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/sbin/semanage

2 - [sudo] yum install policycoreutils-python-utils-2.7-4.fc27.x86_64
```